# Swift unable to find "" in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, function, error-handling

I've encountered this issue a few times where I am trying to either pass a function from one swift file, to another, and I get the error, "Cannot find '_' in scope". I am wondering why this occurs and how to fix it? I have tried creating a public function,  public func fetchJokesAPI() , along with making the class of this function an Observable object so that I am able to pass this function throughout my swift files. Why is the compiler not finding my function in the scope? Below is some code to further give reference to the issue.

```
    //Model

import Foundation

struct DecodingError: Error{}

struct JokesModel: Codable {
    let type: String
    let value: Value
}

// MARK: - Value
struct Value: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let joke: String
     
}








     
class JokesAPI {
    var session: URLSession?
 
  // MARK: Getting random jokes from API endpoint

func fetchJokes() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/") else {
        print("Cannot generate URL")
        return
    }
     var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse) != nil else {
            print("No Response")
            return
        }
          struct JokesResponse: Decodable {
            let data: [JokesModel]
        }

        guard let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            print("No Data")
            return
        }
        do {
            let jokeResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(JokesResponse.self, from: data)
            print(jokeResponse.data)
         } catch {
           print("Error decoding joke response:", error)
              
            
        }
        
    }
    task.resume()
}
 
}





// Another Swift File that is a Coco touch file. 




   

 import UIKit
    import Foundation
    
    class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
        
       private let service = JokesAPI()
        private var joke: [JokesModel]?
        
       
        @IBOutlet var tellAeAJokeButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet var jokeLabel: UILabel!
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            service.fetchJokes()
        }
        
        @IBAction func didPressBtn() {
            
            // MARK: Actions for both fetching a joke from the API, & Text-Speech using AI Voice
            service.fetchJokes()
            joke = [JokesModel]()
            jokeLabel.text = JokesModel().joke
            // Value of type 'JokesModel' has no member 'joke'
            // Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of the class and then call the method using that instance. Or make the function static and use a closure parameter to return the result. In either way you need to reference JokesWebService in some way

Comment: I dragged some folder from other project to my project, so this issue happens (don't know the reason). Solution - Create a new folder and copy all files again from your project- it solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because you need an instance of the class to call your function on.

To get your code working you can do something like this where your viewController takes a service the `JokesWebService` like so, the better option would be to have the service on a viewModel if you already have one but if not this should do the trick to get you started:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var tellAeAJokeButton: UIButton!

    private var service: JokesWebService!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        service = JokesWebService()
    }
    
    @IBAction func didPressBtn() {
        service.fetchJokesAPI() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I guess I am still confused about initializers and what their purpose is within swift or any programing language. Ive learned about singletons and shared instances in general such as URLSession.shared. Now when it comes to creating a shared instance of a function that is nested within another class, this still doesn't make sense to me, because if I make the function public, does that give the ability to use this function between classes ? I am also not certain where let viewController = HomeViewController(service: JokesWebService()) fits in this program

Comment: Btw, I am now getting another error required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UIViewController', but overall I dont not understand what the original issue was, or how to fix this in the future

Comment: @Richard It sounds like you're using storyboard, in which case I've just updated answer and it should work for you.